# Role Based Navigation Items

Tags: .net, angular

I'm learning to develop in .NET and Angular and have run into a brick wall when it comes to role based menu items. I have routing setup and active, and users trying to access areas their role does not provide access to are blocked from entering.  This all works.  The issue I'm having is ensuring they don't see the nav links for those areas that they don't have access too.  (If it helps at all, I'm using the CoreUI admin theme as the base for this).

My project has 4 roles:

- GlobalAdmin
- ClientAdmin
- LocationAdmin
- ReportsOnly

Access is controlled by Core Identity in the .NET application. On the angular side of things I was setting up a role directive used to control the viewing of the nav links using this directive and adding *appHasRole="['GlobalAdmin']" for whichever role was required.  This doesn't work though as my sidebar builds my links by grabbing them from the _nav.ts file.

Is anyone able to help me out with adding this functionality?  I've even tried using seperate _nav files for each role which I know isnt optimal, and quickly discovered if someone has more than one role, both nav bars are displayed.

This is how my nav system is currently built.

_nav.ts (Note, its the Management and its Children that require the GlobalAdmin role, and the Inspections requires the LocationsAdmin role for examples).

```
import { INavData } from '@coreui/angular';

export const navItems: INavData[] = [
  {
    name: 'Dashboard',
    url: '/dashboard',
    icon: 'icon-speedometer',
    badge: {
      variant: 'info',
      text: 'NEW'
    }
  },
  {
    title: true,
    name: 'Licensing'
  },
  {
    name: 'Manage',
    url: '/manage',
    icon: 'icon-settings',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Register',
        url: '/manage/register',
        icon: 'icon-star'
      },
      {
        name: 'Clients',
        url: '/manage/clients',
        icon: 'icon-user'
      },
      {
        name: 'Locations',
        url: '/manage/locations',
        icon: 'icon-location-pin'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: true,
    name: 'Site Management'
  },
  {
  name: 'Inspections',
    url: '/inspections',
    icon: 'icon-magnifying-glass',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Setup',
        url: '/inspections/setup',
        icon: 'icon-cursor'
      },
      {
        name: 'Reports',
        url: '/inspections/reports',
        icon: 'icon-cursor'
      }
    ]
  }
```

default-layout component that displays the SPA and contains the sidebar:

```
  <app-sidebar #appSidebar [fixed]="true" [display]="'lg'" [minimized]="sidebarMinimized" (minimizedChange)="toggleMinimize($event)">
    <app-sidebar-nav [navItems]="navItems" *appHasRole="['GlobalAdmin']" [perfectScrollbar] [disabled]="appSidebar.minimized"></app-sidebar-nav>
    <app-sidebar-minimizer></app-sidebar-minimizer>
  </app-sidebar>
```

.NET API startup.cs file containing the role policy:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("RequireGlobalAdminRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("GlobalAdmin"));
                options.AddPolicy("RequireClientAdminRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("GlobalAdmin", "ClientAdmin"));
                options.AddPolicy("RequireLocationAdminRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("GlobalAdmin", "ClientAdmin", "LocationAdmin"));
                options.AddPolicy("RequireReportsOnlyRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("GlobalAdmin", "ClientAdmin", "LocationAdmin", "ReportsOnly"));
            });
```

Any assistance on this would be GREATLY appreciated.  I've been pulling my hair out on this for 4 days now trying to figure out a way.

Edit: app-sidebar-nav.d.ts

```
import { OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { INavData } from './app-sidebar-nav';
import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
export declare class AppSidebarNavComponent implements OnChanges {
    router: Router;
    navItems: INavData[];
    _sidebarBav: boolean;
    role: string;
    navItemsArray: INavData[];
    constructor(router: Router);
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void;
    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<AppSidebarNavComponent>;
    static ɵcmp: ɵngcc0.ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta<AppSidebarNavComponent, 
"app-sidebar-nav, cui-sidebar-nav", never, { 'navItems': "navItems", 
'role': "role" }, {}, never>;
}

//# sourceMappingURL=app-sidebar-nav.component.d.ts.map
```

Comment: You must create menu dynamically for this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in a similar situation, where I wanted to add roles and permissions to each menu item to ensure that users only had a menu filled only with items they're allowed to see.  The accepted answer up top was close, but no cigar, because of where the *ngIf was suggested to reside. I finally implemented a rather easy solution after running across this: https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-angular-admin-template/issues/161

1. I created an interface to extend INavData:

   ```
   export interface MyINavData extends INavData {
      role?: string;
      permissions?: string[]; 
    }
   ```
2. Create a service:

   ```
    import { navigation } from '@app/_nav';
     @Injectable({
       providedIn: 'root'
     })
    export class AppSidebarService {
        items$: Observable<MyINavData[]>;
         navItems = navigation;

     constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) {
        this.items$ = this.getSidebarItems();
     }

     private getSidebarItems(): Observable<MyINavData []> {
       let navItems: MyINavData [] = new Array<MyINavData >();
       this.navItems.forEach((item) =>{
           //...do some logic here          
       });
       return of(navItems);
    }
   ```

   }
3. Updated the .html page calling the sidebar:

   ```
   <!--<app-sidebar-nav [navItems]="navItems"...</app-sidebar-nav>-->
   <app-sidebar-nav [navItems]="sidebar.items$ | async" ...</app-sidebar-nav>
   ```
4. Make sure the service is injected in the calling Component.

   ```
    constructor(..., private sidebarService: AppSidebarService)
   ```

Comment: Hey Briana!  

Thanks for this. I'm trying to implement it in my app.  Are you able to let me know what KhoINavData refers to?  This isn't within my project.

Comment: @Sapper6fd, That was my extension  (MyINavData = KhoINavData in question) . Looks like I changed the name for posting to SO in one area, but not the other...I've updated my answer properly.

Comment: {
        name: 'Overview',
        url: 'analytics/overview',
        icon: 'icon-magnifier',
        attributes:{
          role: ["RequireGlobalAdminRole"]
        }
      }

Comment: How `sidebar.items$ ` is available in html? In my case it says `Property 'sidebar' does not exist on type 'DefaultLayoutComponent'`.

Comment: @RNKushwaha In the calling component receiving the DI for the AppSidebarService, you can create a property such as:   public navItems$: BehaviorSubject<MyINavData[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Array<MyINavData>>(new Array<MyINavData>());  Then somewhere on the component, fill that property by calling the AppSidebarService function getSidebarItems();

Comment: Can you please share code for same. In my case I want to show menu based on role admin,user,manager. But not able to connect all the things in proper way.

Comment: if possible, please share code snippet for sidebar.items$ implementation

Comment: Can you share your implementation of the default layout component as my nav items are always empty when the page is loaded, then after my api endpoint finishes the nav items do not re-populate

Comment: @rohit, I posted a block of code in response below that shows the sidebar service in more detail. Hope that helps. Sam - not sure what you're using, but this is one of the benefits for me using the BehaviorSubject

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add the required role for each nav item in the  `navItems`, for example:

```
import { INavData } from '@coreui/angular';

export const navItems: INavData[] = [
  {
    name: 'Dashboard',
    url: '/dashboard',
    icon: 'icon-speedometer',
    badge: {
      variant: 'info',
      text: 'NEW'
    },
    role:'GlobalAdmin' //add it like this
  },
```

and in your nav item implementation, get the current role and use it to render it or hide using the below example code:

```
<nav-item *ngIf='currentRole==item.role'></nav-item>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm not really sure how I would implement that (as I'm new to development and Angular).  Are you able to provide a bit more input on that?

Comment: please share your `app-sidebar-nav` implementation (.ts and .html files) so I can edit my answer based on it.

Comment: Hey Mu'men Tayyem!  I've added the app-sidebar-nav to the bottom of my original post.  There is no html component for it though.  I really do appreciate you help while I learn this.  If it makes it easier, I can also add the git repo as well.

Comment: please add the git repo, it will be easier for me to help.

Comment: I can see that you're using CoreUI. I believe you need to do your own implementation to get that feature. kindly check the below link: https://github.com/ljl8086/CoreUI-Angular/blob/master/Angular4_CLI_Full_Project/src/app/components/app-sidebar-nav/app-sidebar-nav.component.ts
it's their implementation for app-sidebar,, which has nothing related to roles.

Comment: Ahhhh I have been searching high and low for an answer.  This is something I havent seen.  Thanks for looking at this for me.  Its greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problem dear, it would help me to mark my answer as correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have an app.initializer.ts that is ran when the app is loaded to get all global type of info needed, like User info and all related details. Once I've got the user info, I use my sidebar.service to get the user's menu. Obviously, this will be determined by how you build your permissions and roles. But, here is my example:
(I added some to [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqe5bc?file=src/app/app.component.html) to hopefully make easier to review)

```
   if (user?.id != undefined) {
       that.sidebarService.getCurrentUserMenu(user).subscribe((items) => {
           that.navItems$.next(items);
           resolve();
        });
    }
```

Then in the sidebar.service.ts

```
export class AppSidebarService { 
    private menuItems$: BehaviorSubject<KhoINavData[]> = 
              new BehaviorSubject<KhoINavData[]>(new Array<KhoINavData>());

   constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

   public getCurrentUserMenu = (user: GraphUser) =>  {  
       //first, get all items not requiring any permissions  
      let items: KhoINavData[] =  navigation.filter(x => x.allowed == null);
      if (user.id != undefined && user.permissions.length > 0) {
      let navItemsRequiringPermissions: KhoINavData[] =  navigation.filter(x => x.allowed != null);
      let allItems: KhoINavData[] = navigation;

      //super-users have access to everything
     if(user.permissions.find(x => x.permissionActionType.actionName == TypeOfPermissionTypes.everything && x.permissionActionType.permissionActionRole.roleName == TypeOfPermissionRoles.superuser) != undefined){
          items = allItems;
      }else{
         let userAuthorizedPermissions = [
            ...new Set(
              user.permissions.map((x) => [
              x.permissionActionType.permissionActionRole.roleName,
              x.permissionActionType.actionName,
            ])
         ),
       ];
 
    //find all items requiring this permission and push
    navItemsRequiringPermissions.filter(item => {
      let isAuthorized: boolean = false;
      
      item.allowed.forEach((neededPermission) => {
        //does the user have this role?
        isAuthorized = userAuthorizedPermissions.filter((x) => x[0] == neededPermission.role).length > 0 ? true : false;
        if (isAuthorized) {
          if (neededPermission.types != undefined) {
            //ex: (8) ['AP DATA', 'AR DATA', 'CUSTOMER DATA', 'INVENTORY DATA', 'LOCATION DATA', 'POSTING GROUP DATA', 'SALESPERSON DATA', 'VENDOR DATA']
            let userAuthTypes = userAuthorizedPermissions
              .filter((x) => x[0] == neededPermission.role)
              .map((x) => x[1]);
            //does the user have any of the required types?
            isAuthorized = extendArray(userAuthTypes).findOne(
              userAuthTypes,
              neededPermission.types
            );
          }
        }
      });
      
      if (isAuthorized) {
        items.push(item);
       }
     })
   }
} 
   return of(items).pipe(
    tap(() => { this.menuItems$.next(
        items.sort((a, b) => (a.displayOrder < b.displayOrder ? -1 : 1))
    );}),
    share()
    ) as BehaviorSubject<KhoINavData[]>;
  }
}
```